# Ignore code coverage for unit tests in EclEmma

Tags: java, eclipse, code-coverage, eclemma

I have [configured EclEmma not to instrument my unit tests](http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference/ch02s06s02.html#n11405) which works fine. However, the editor still highlights the test code as not covered. I want no highlighting in unit tests because they are not instrumented to detect coverage. How can I do this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I did the following steps:

1. Go to **Preferences->Java->Code Coverage** and
2. set the **"Only path entries matching"** option to `src/main/java`

It seems to work nicely.

Comment: This has the added bonus of not requiring configuration of each project.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did.

Comment: This is the best solution imo

Comment: make sure you create a new coverage configuration after making the changes in Preferences.

Comment: this didn't work for me. including just /src/ made coverage results not display at all, the other answer about checking items in coverage configuration did work

Answer (score 40):

The include/exclude filter settings in the Preferences window apply to class name/package patterns for all projects. To control the files at the folder/path level you must set it per-project.

1. Right-click the project
2. Select **Coverage As | Coverage Configurations...**
3. Select the project under the **Junit** subtree
4. Select the **Coverage** tab on the right
5. Uncheck the folder containing your tests, e.g., `src/test/java`
6. Click **Apply**
7. Click **Close** (or **Coverage** to run immediately)

These settings will apply every time you run the coverage in the future without having to open the configuration window.