# How to exclude code (packages) in jococo, eclemma

Tags: code-coverage, eclemma

I am trying to exclude code in jococo. I have given   for the package that I want to exclude and vice versa   tags in my code for the package that I want to include.

but still ECLEMMA while junit coverage is reading whole code i.e. all packages and hence my code coverage goes down.

Here is my code:

```
              <includes>
               <include>com.cfgh.controller.*</include>
               <include>com.cfgh.service.*</include>
               <include>com.cfgh.repository.*</include>
              </includes>

               <excludes>
               <exclude>com.cfgh.config.*</exclude>
               <exclude>com.cfgh.model.dto.*</exclude>
               <exclude>com.cfgh.model.entity.*</exclude>
               <exclude>com.cfgh.repository.*</exclude>
               <exclude>com.cfgh.exception.handler.*</exclude>
```

The include and exclude tags appear in green in pom.xml file, but still it is not reading it.
Can someone please guide me here in right direction.Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coverage exclusion in Eclipse \[EclEmma\] is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703999/coverage-exclusion-in-eclipse-eclemma-is-not-working)

Comment: While EclEmma under the hood uses JaCoCo, it doesn't read jacoco-maven-plugin configuration. As of today there is no way to exclude packages in EclEmma. Exclusions specified for jacoco-maven-plugin affect only report generated by it.