# Jacoco - Exclude package from coverage report

Tags: java, maven-2, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a problem with Jacoco, I try to exclude a package from coverage, this is my configuration.

[image: Maven configuration]

But, report doesn't exclude it and this problem generating a low coverage in my project.

[image: Jacoco Report]

Thanks!

Comment: What is shown on screenshot doesn't look like HTML report generated by jacoco-maven-plugin, and looks more like Eclipse EclEmma. If so then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456971/how-to-exclude-code-packages-in-jococo-eclemma#comment86052437_49456971