# Why EclEmma don't allow to ignore a class from the total percentage of the coverage?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-coverage, eclemma

I look around and can't take off a class,
that class is in the package that i need to test and take the code coverage.
But that class in specific i don't want to be considered in the total percentage,
Because that afect my coverage measure,
Well in my research i found that EclEmma can't do this.

What is this about?
 - its maybe that is complecated because  the way eclemma relaize the code-coverage 
 - or is bad practice remove class from and thats why eclemma dont allow it.
 - maybe the eclemma team are working in this feature?

I already try Preferences->Java->Code Coverage -> Exclude
but this still taking the class in the measure with 0% so that affect my code-coverage

even in the documentation page of Eclemma said this:

> Warning: Use these options with caution! Invalid entries might break the code coverage launcher. Also do not use these options to define the scope of your analysis. Excluded classes will still show as not covered.

Comment: Can you give an example where this makes sense (without an anti-pattern)? See here who the Eclemma team is, what they have done and what they are working on (open bugs): https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.eclemma

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coverage exclusion in Eclipse \[EclEmma\] is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703999/coverage-exclusion-in-eclipse-eclemma-is-not-working)

Comment: @Godin, i'm asking why this happend, if someone knows why EclEmma did not add this  option