# What does red highlight in unit test mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, code-coverage, eclemma

I run a unit test, and see how much of the class I'm testing against is covered, and I see its all green (covered). But in my unit test itself, I see red high lights. What does this mean? I don't see any information about the highlights in the tests themselves in the Eclemma documentation.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot please?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upload the code because it is copyright.

Comment: Try to build small example that will reproduce the same problem, but in isolation from your copyrighted code (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Red could mean e.g. that the test failed or that something is not covered, depending what is red. Maybe, you could attach a screenshot.

Comment: I assume (but I'm not sure) that your test failed.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse folders containing main code and test code - are source folders. By default EclEmma performs analysis of all source folders and highlight has the same semantic everywhere. If you're not interested in highlighting in certain folders (such as folders containing tests), then you can exclude as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40596673/244993

Comment: Right, but when I'm running the unit test, then all of the lines of the test are being executed...therefore, we should see that all lines in the unit test are highlighted with green. Instead of that, I'm seeing that some tests are highlighted red

Comment: @JanacMeena If just some tests highlighted as red, then they are somehow specific. Without Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) people can only make guesses. Do they test that exception is thrown? Which version of EclEmma do you use? etc. And I doubt that you'll get more than what was already said without providing more context/details, so could you please provide at least screenshot as have been asked before?

Answer (score 1):

The Test itself is not tested and so the coverage is zero. 
You only want to know the coverage of the class under test and not from the test.

Answer (score 0):

In my POM.xml JUnit's scope is `test`. I removed the scope and the problem is solved.

I don't believe that this is the best possible solution; Eclipse should be able to accept the scope `test`, but I haven't been able to work out how to do this.

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Nope. The majority of this isn't an answer - it's a question. Remove that and you have an answer. Currently, however, the majority of this answer is a question.